# How to join two select on same table

Tags: mysql

I have two select statement like

```
Select author_id, count(text) from posts group by author_id

select author_id, count(text) from posts where postcounter =1 group by author_id
```

Is there a way to combine in a single query the two statements? Results differ in length, so it is needed to insert some 0s in the second resultset.

Many thanks for any help

Best regards,
Simone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this in a single query using:

```
Select author_id, 
  count(text) TextCount,
  count(case when postcounter=1 then text end) PostCount
from posts 
group by author_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select author_id, 
   sum(case when postcounter = 1 then 1 else 0 end) count1, 
   sum(case when postcounter <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) count2,
   count(text) allcount
from posts  
group by author_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a union all statement?

```
   SELECT `id`,sum(`count`) FROM (
Select  author_id as `id`, count(text) as `count` from posts group by author_id 
UNION ALL 
select author_id as `id`, count(text) as `count` from posts where postcounter =1 group by author_id
    )
```